Using animateFloatAsState doesn't work with a duration
I am trying to create an animation so that the saturation will animate for 1000 ms. However, with the code below it happens instantly.
This the code snippet
val saturation by animateFloatAsState(
    targetValue = if (isSelected) 1f else 0f,
    animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 1_000)
)

var rememberSaturation = remember(saturation) {
    ColorMatrix().apply {
        this.setToSaturation(if (isSelected) 1f else 0f)
    }
}

I am using it like this:
 Image(
                modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp),
                painter = painterResource(currencyCode.flag),
                contentDescription = null,
                colorFilter = ColorFilter.colorMatrix(rememberSaturation)
            )

I am trying to animate the flag when the user taps on it.


Nothing happens because you never use the animateFloatAsState's result (i.e., saturation).
Change rememberSaturation to this instead:
val rememberSaturation = remember(saturation) {
    ColorMatrix().apply { setToSaturation(saturation) }
}

Now the animated value is used and you will see the animation in Image.

the aforementioned repository
com.scwang.wave:MultiWaveHeader:1.0.0

is now remains unreachable, you can use this instead:
implementation 'io.openharmony.tpc.thirdlib:MultiWaveHeader:1.0.1'

Link to the Maven Repo is here.

You can use implementation ‘com.scwang.wave:MultiWaveHeader:1.0.0’(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wave-animation-in-android/)
Or Gif

I don't think that link is related to my question
